# How to update class override when upgrading module to new version in Prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

Let's say there is a module with version 0.1.

This module already have overrides applied for example to classes/Cart.php.

New requirement comes in and we make a change to an already overridden classes/Cart.php.

To apply new change we update module version to 0.2, but after update Prestashop doesn't reapply new overrides. I also tried placing upgrade script in upgrade folder which I confirmed was executing but old override is still there.

How do you apply new overrides without reinstalling the module?

Comment: Did you have any success with this? My best idea this far is to run uninstallOverrides, overwrite the overridden files with new ones from the upgrade folder and then run installOverrides. Have you tried something similar?

Comment: I postponed this functionality until it's really needed. In general I had the similar approach in mind to what you explained. BUT! If you look at the logic for uninstallOverrides it's using reflection to determine if active override is same as the one you have in the module. That means it's not going to take your new override file as reference for doing uninstall so overrides are not going to be uninstalled. When doing installOverrieds after that it will complain about conflict. To make this work there should be some versioning system in place for override files. That's why I left it for later

Comment: I was a bit unclear. My idea was to keep the new override files in a folder named upgrade/overrides. In the upgrade code you could then run uninstallOverrides which would look at the old files and removes the override. Then you replace the module/override files with upgrade/override and run installOverrides afterwards. Problem with this approach is handling new installs and would require always copying from latest upgrade/override folder before running full installer. I can post a complete answer with examples if I implement it.

Comment: Then we understand each other correctly :). What I was expanding on is that you need some versioning of those overrides. Same as you are doing with upgrade scripts. But since upgrade scripts have versioning built into the core you would have to develop system of your own. Example implementation would be to prefix/suffix overrides with version numbers. And you would have to keep overrides in a separate directory and copy them to /overrides after uninstallOverrides is complete. Of course you would have to cover all corner cases and think it through so I have bad gut feeling about it.

Answer (score 2):

In the upgrade method you could run in sequence uninstallOverrides and installOverrides, it would result in installing the state of your overrides at your current version.

File upgrade/upgrade-1.1.0.php:

```
function upgrade_module_1_1_0($module)
{
    $module->uninstallOverrides();
    $module->installOverrides();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that the only way is to manually remove and copy new override file to /override folder, checking that the current overrided file is actually yours (md5 checksum p.ex.).

Comment: That is a very bad idea, because you would uninstall any other method overrides from other modules. Also, at least since 1.6.0.14 the md5 check wouldn't work because PrestaShop adds comments regarding your module.